# Grep console tab disappeared from IntelliJ Debug area

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins

Grep console tab disappeared from IntelliJ Debug area.

How can I make it appear again?

Comment: Do you have https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console/ plug-in enabled?

Comment: yes, it is enabled under Plugins

Comment: Restarted IntelliJ, and now it is back - weird.

Comment: Figured it out. Right-click in the regular console and select "Grep" menu item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grep console tab [opens via the context menu](https://i.imgur.com/sPK1xDs.gifv) (assuming you have the [corresponding plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console/) installed and enabled).